# Unsubscribe option in Email using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, unsubscribe

I have been sending email from C# and they are working fine, but now I am also looking for the functionality to allow receiver to unsubscribe.
I am unable to get how to proceed as I have no idea.
I googled enough so need some hint.

Below is my code:

```
  MailMessage loginInfo = new MailMessage();
  loginInfo.To.Add(EmailTxt.Text.ToString());
  loginInfo.From = new MailAddress(sEmailId);
  loginInfo.Subject = "Subject";
  loginInfo.Body = "Your username is: " +;
  loginInfo.IsBodyHtml = true;

  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
  smtp.Host = sHost;
  smtp.Port = 25;
  smtp.EnableSsl = false;
  smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
  smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
  smtp.Send(loginInfo);
```

Comment: Just send them a link to unsubscribe... am I missing something?

Comment: How does this code help you to "unsubscribe" from whatever you want to be able to unsubscribe from?

Comment: i hope OP shows the code for sending Email and asking the best approach to unsubscribe, please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You need to log users to a table with a boolean/bit unsubscribe column. the default would be 0 once they click on unsubscribe then you will update this column to 1 and send your email according to this column

Comment: @ Sudhakar: Thanks yes you are correct. And if some one had read properly than I am showing what I know and also written what I want to know. :)

Comment: @ Sam: Yes I get and just wanted to know how will I be catching their click in my web application? Or do I need to make another application to get when they click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unsubscribing is easy if you are already maintaining the users email id's in Database.

**Please follow the below steps:**

**Step 1:** Create an extra column in user table as `unsubscribe` in database. 
it will take `true` or `false` as values.
set default to `false` so that every subscribed user gets email.

Note : Before sending Mails to users please check their `unsubscribe` column.
if it is false send an Email.
if it is true don't send an Email as they have unsubscribed.

**Step2:** Create an unsubscribing URL as below:

```
http://mywebsite.com/unsubscribeme/emailID=xyz@gmail.com
```

**Step3:** Send this URL to user as unsubscribe URL so that whenever he feels to unsubscribe he can do that simply by clicking on that URL.

**Step4:** once if user clicks on given URL read the QueryString value of emailID `emailID=xyz@gmail.com`

**Step5:** Update the user table info by setting the `unsubscribe` column value to `true`.

Example :

```
 //get user EmailID by QueryString as below:
 String EmailID=Reques.QueryString["emailID"].ToString();

//Update the usertable as below:
String Command ="update usertable set unsubscribe='true' where emailid='"+EmailID+"'";
```

Comment: I get, but there is one doubt, how will I get to know when he will be clicking on unsubscribe link, as I have a web application, so do I need to make application to get back?

Comment: Also +1: for giving me an idea. :)

Comment: @ItiTyagi: if user clicks on the given url(i mean in the solution) he will be redirected your your webpage from where you can proceed further by taking the emailid from the querystring. if not clarified please let me know.

Comment: I have a secure application where only few staff have access, these staff send email to their customers, so cannot give them an access. I think I will need to make another short single page web appl. What say?

Comment: @ItiTyagi: "can't give access" by you mean you can't even allow others to open single page from your website, if you are maintaining  User Management it won't be a problem.

Comment: This allows anyone to unsubscribe anyone else just by knowing their email address

Comment: @thelem, not only that. SQL-injection in example. How user with such rating can post answers like that?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have your subscribers stored somewhere. So the easy way to unsubscribe is to remove the record from the store by its email-address.

It has nothing to do with the SmtpClient class.

Comment: Ok, that was some where in my mind, that I will be marking users as unsubscribers.

Comment: Thank you so much, +1 for giving me an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a mailing list includes a list of email addresses, usually saved in a database. Your code adds the receiver from an "EmailTxt", I guess a textbox?

- As long as you do not save email addresses somewhere, there is no need to unsubscribe
- If you save email addresses, then create another file that allows people to unsubcribe.

An unsubscribe file would usually function as follows:

- receive the email address to unsubscribe as a querystring parameter
- display this email address in a single textbox, along with an "unsubscribe" button
- if the user clicks this button, then remove the email address from the database.

Comment: @ Markus: Thanks buddy, I appreciate and +1: for giving a hint. :)